# How to map nested JSON properties collected with JS fetch API and SWR

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch-api, swr

I have following JSON API, permanently provided by the Swiss Government.

https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/14856203/master

I am trying to list some content that does not appear in the first level – in my case some voting statistics (`jaStimmenInProzent`) of every vote (`vorlagenId`):

[image: Screenshot API]

I am using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [Vercel SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/). Unfortunately I couldn’t find a tutorial/example where the content that is mapped does not appear on the first level. Any Idea how to proceed and getting the `vorlagen` array listed? I tried following without success ([see sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sammet-qfe03?file=/src/App.js:0-563)):

```js
import useSWR from "swr";
import "./styles.css";

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((response) => response.json());

export default function App() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://app-prod-static-voteinfo.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/ogd/sd-t-17-02-20201129-eidgAbstimmung.json",
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return <h1>this is an error: {error}</h1>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data ? (
        data.map((vorlagen) => <h1>{vorlagenId}</h1>)
      ) : (
        <h1>loading...</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data contains `schweiz` property which includes `vorlgen` property which is an array. You won't be able to map directly on your `data`.

You'd have to map over `data.schweiz.vorlagen` which will eventually give you access to the required subproperties.

```
{data ? (
    data.schweiz.volragen.map((vorlagen) => (
      <div>
        <h1>{vorlgen.vorlagenId}</h1>
        <h4>{volragen.resultat.jaStimmenInProzent}</h4>
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
  <h1>loading...</h1>
)}
```

Comment: Thank you AdityaParab, it works. I updated codesandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sammet-qfe03?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the JSON file at the top is the whole thing at the URL, then you just aren't accessing it right, here is an example

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import "./styles.css";

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((response) => response.json());

export default function App() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://app-prod-static-voteinfo.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/ogd/sd-t-17-02-20201129-eidgAbstimmung.json",
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return <h1>this is an error: {error}</h1>;
   

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data ? (
        data.schwiez.vorlagen.map((value) => <h1>{value.vorlagenId}</h1><p>{value.resultat.jaStimmenInProzent}</p>)
      ) : (
        <h1>loading...</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

thought really you want to only download the data you're going to access so if you have control over the server you download it from, consider adding a function that maps it server-side and before sending it (only if you arent using some of the data of course).

Im no god but in theory this should work (I haven't tested it)

sorry for any typos in the spelling of the values

Comment: Thank you Huddy for your appreciated feedback, it works! I updated the sandbox as mentioned in the comment above already.  I did accept the answer from AdityaParab since he was a bit earlier. Hope that is ok for you.